# Is there any way to check if the Component exists before importing that react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having a scenario in that i want to load a component and render it if the file exists for that component, If not return another component.

```
if('./Shared/MyComponent') exists then 
Import MyCompoent from './Shared/MyCompoent'
Else
Import MyCompoent from './Shared/MyNewCompoent'
```

Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: Interesting. May I ask why `MyComponent` may not exist? There might be some other way to go about it.

Comment: I am creating React native project which can generate multiple apps out of it with same function but different in Landing Page (Home page) and different icon.  Just trying to achieve this by this if custom page exists load that or load the base common page

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you could always create the `MyComponent` file, but if you are not using it it would export an empty function. It would also export an `isActive` bool which you can use in the render method of the component importing it, e.g. `import MyComponent, { isActive } from './Shared/MyComponent'`

Comment: Can't achieve this using React.Lazy .?

Comment: @Tholle. In my case, I'm using NextJS, and sometimes, when developing new feature, new Component, I want to be able to load component directly without having to load all App. But I also need to git track the `/pages/dev.js` file as a guide, and the component it calls inside can be git ignore, hence exists only on dev environment when a developer is using it.

Comment: Thank you the information ("Is there any way to achieve this").
What is the question?

Answer (score -3):

Uhm it's a little bit hacky and probably there are more polished solutions, but this *should* work (can't test right now)

```
try {
 import MyComponent from './component'
} catch (e) {
 import MyComponent from './new-component'
}
```